# How do I solve this trig substitution?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

So for the problem

> $$\int \frac{2x + 3} {(x^2+4)^3} dx$$

I know that I need to separate the integral into

$$\int \frac{2x } {(x^2+4)^3} dx+\int \frac{ 3} {(x^2+4)^3} dx$$

but I run into problems with $\int \frac{ 3} {(x^2+4)^3} dx$ because I know that I am expected to use trig substitution for it, but I have basically no experience with trig sub when there is no square root.

Comment: Try $x=2\tan t$.

Answer (score 3):

This one's quite involved. With $x=2\tan t$,$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+4)^3}&=\tfrac{1}{32}\int\cos^4tdt\\&=\tfrac{1}{256}\int(3+4\cos2t+\cos4t)dt\\&=\tfrac{1}{256}(3t+2\sin2t+\tfrac14\sin4t)+C\\&=\tfrac{1}{256}\left(3\arctan\tfrac{x}{2}+\tfrac{2x(3x^2+20)}{(x^2+4)^2}\right)+C\end{align}$$(I'll leave you to fill in all the steps.)

Comment: can you expand more on how you replace t on the final step?

Comment: @strstr Using $\sin2t=\frac{2\tan t}{\sec^2t}$ and $\sin 4t=2\sin 2t\left(\tfrac{2}{\sec^2t}-1\right)$, and $\sec^2t=1+x^2/4$.